# FEC API key form submit does nothing

Tags: usa, government, elections, federal

I visit https://api.open.fec.gov/developers/ , fill out the form titled "Sign up for an API key", and press "Signup". The button briefly changes to "Loading...", then flips back to "Submit". Nothing else happens and I receive no email. I've tried Chrome 85.0.4183.102 and Safari 13.1.2 (15609.3.5.1.3).